# Why $n^{\log_2 n}$ almost equals $2^{\log^2_2 n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Just by doing some calculations:

```
(loop for n from 2 below 33 collect (- (expt n (log n 2)) (expt 2 (expt (log n 2) 2))))
(0.0 0.0 0.0 3.8146973e-6 -1.5258789e-5 -1.5258789e-5 0.0 -1.2207031e-4
 2.4414063e-4 -9.765625e-4 -0.0043945313 0.0048828125 -0.001953125 0.0078125
 0.0 -0.0625 -0.203125 -0.125 0.0625 0.0 0.375 0.625 2.0 1.0 -2.0 0.5 5.0 -8.0
 6.0 2.0 0.0)
```

Or, in other words, sequence defined using formula: $n^{\log_2 n}-2^{\log^2_2 n}$ appears to have numbers very close to zero (and exactly zero, when $\log_2 n$ is a whole number.)

I was "hoping" it would be always zeros, but this is unlikely to be a round-off error.

PS. $\log^x_y z$ means logarithm basis $y$ of $z$ raised to the $x^{th}$ power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From $n^a=2^{a\log_2 n}$, which holds for any $a$, you **do** get $$n^{\log_2 n} = 2^{\log^2_2 n}$$
(not "almost equal": *actually* equal).

Comment: Oh, great. Thanks. It was just unexpectedly big round-off error for the kind of calculation, so I began to doubt myself.

Comment: Which language did you use for the numerical computations? (I don't recognize it.)

Comment: It's Common Lisp, but now I'm guessing it must've used 16bit floats or something strange like that to get this sort of error. When I reset it to use double-precision floats, the errors are within 1.0e-8.

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{\log_2^2n}$$
$$=2^{(\log_2n)(\log_2n)}$$
$$=2^{\log_2(n^{\log_2n})}$$
$$=n^{\log_2n}$$